# Is the class of non-regular languages closed against Kleene star?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

How to prove that if a language A is not regular then A* isn't regular either?

I have tried the usual methods with no result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prove that a language is not regular?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular)

Comment: What are the "usual methods" you tried?

Comment: I tried everything in that link, and couldn't work it out. That works as reply to both.

Comment: What makes you think that this claim is correct?

Comment: If you don't find a proof, look for a counter-example...

Comment: It is just an intuition. I unsuccessfully looked for counter-examples too.

Comment: Hint: try a non-regular language over a unary alphabet $\{a\}$. See where that gets you.

Comment: Turns out that my intuition was wrong. I did not think of non-regular languages over unary alphabets!

Comment: For Kleene star for a language over unary alphabet, see [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10013/if-l-is-a-subset-of-0-then-how-can-we-show-that-l-is-regular).

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to consider languages over a unary alphabet. Consider, for instance, non-regular languages containing at least all strings of length one over any alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $L$ is any language over the alphabet $\Sigma$. If $L$ is not regular then so is $L+\Sigma$, yet $(L+\Sigma)^* = \Sigma^*$ is regular.

Comment: Excellent answer; although I fail to see how this is a hint, so much as a complete proof that the claim is false.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Does + mean union here?

Comment: @Turbo. That's right.