# Proving that $L=\{ w \mid \lvert w \rvert$ is prime $\}$* is a regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

I'm trying to prove that the following languague is a regular language:

**$L=\{ w \mid \lvert w \rvert$ is prime $\}$***

What I have thought is to divide each word $w \in L$ into subwords of length 2 if the word is even and and if the word is odd end with a suffix of length 3, in this way I would get the following regular expression:

**(aa + ab + ba + bb)*** **(aaa + aba + abb + aab + baa + bab + bba + bbb + $\epsilon$)**

Is my reasoning correct?

Otherwise I would appreciate so much any help.

Comment: is the language the kleenee-star of $\{w| \space |w| \text{ is prime}\}$?

Comment: Looks good. Any particular reason that you suspect it's incorrect? (we usually discourage questions of the form "check my answer").

Comment: @nirshahar indeed, that's right

Comment: @Shaull Not entirely, I just wasn't sure if my reasoning was correct. I am sorry ^^"

Comment: @Shaull do i have to delete this post or something?

Comment: @Shaull I also hear other possible ways to solve it

Comment: @jackesgamero No need to delete. Anyway, it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are provided the language :

$$L=\{w| |w| \text{ is prime} \}^*$$

Let us investigate the type of strings in $L$. We see that $L$ has such strings whose length is either zero or can be expressed as a sum of prime numbers. i.e. if $x \in L$ then we have :

$$|x| = \begin{cases}
       0 \text{ or}\\
       \Sigma p_i \text{ where $p_i$ $\in$ Set of all prime numbers}\\
\end{cases}$$

Now let us consider first the set of all strings of even length. i.e. $|x| = 2k , \text{$k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k\geq 0$}$

So given any string of even length, we can write it as a concatenation of $0$ or more number strings of length $2$, but we see that $2$ is a prime number. So any string of even length $\in L$ and can be expressed by the regular expression :
$$((a+b)(a+b))^*$$

From the above expression, we can generate strings of length $0,2,4,...$ $\tag 1$

Let us consider the strings of odd length.

Let us consider the string of length $1$. But $1$ is not a prime number. So strings of length $1$ cannot be present in $L$. So we are left with the odd numbers $3,5,7,...$ or
$$|x|= 2\lambda+1, \text{$\lambda \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lambda\geq 1$} \tag 2$$
$$\implies |x| = 3+ (2\lambda+1 -3) = 3+ (2\lambda -2)=3+ 2(\lambda -1)$$
$$|x| = 3+2\mu \text{ , $\mu \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mu\geq 0$}$$

Now $3$ and $2$ are prime numbers. So any odd length string of length greater than $1$ can be represented by the concatenation of a string of prime length $3$ followed by zero or more numbers of strings of prime length $2$, which can be represented by the regular expression:

$$(a+b)(a+b)(a+b)((a+b)(a+b))^*$$

From the above two calculations we can say that L:

$$L = ((a+b)(a+b))^*+(a+b)(a+b)(a+b)((a+b)(a+b))^*$$

This is how we suggest that $L$ is a regular language.

Now as far as the language is concerned, we see from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we see that strings in $L$ have lengths $0,2,3,4,5,6,...$, which is simply :

$$L= \epsilon + (a+b)(a+b)(a+b)^*$$

Answer (score 4):

I let you verify that the submonoid of $(\Bbb N, +)$ generated by $2$ and $3$ is equal to ${\Bbb N} - \{1\}$. It follows that
$$
K = \bigl\{w \in A^* \mid |w| = 2 \text{ or } |w| = 3\bigr\}^* = A^* - A
$$
Now $K \subseteq L$ and $L \cap A = \emptyset$. Thus $K = L$.

Answer (score 3):

In fact this follows from a general property of the star operation. When we start with an *arbitrary* language $L$ of *all* strings of certain lengths, then the star $L^*$ of that language is always regular. More precisely:

> Let $A\subseteq \mathbb N$, and $L = \{w\in \Sigma^*\mid |w|\in A\}$.
> Then $L^*$ is regular.

This is a consequence of a property of unary languages, i.e., languages over a single symbol. See this question:
[If $L$  is a subset of  $\{0\}^∗$ , then how can we show that  $L^∗$  is regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/10013/4287)

So for $\Sigma = \{0\}$ the statement above is true. For larger alphabets perform an alphabetic substitution (say $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$, then in a regular expression for $L^*$ replace every $0$ by $(a+b)$).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. However we can simplify this a bit: $\epsilon + (a+b)^2(a+b)^*$.

The language is all words with length $\neq 1$. Thanks to @Emil Jerabek and @Nathaniel for pointing this out in the comments! (and correcting me multiple times!)

Comment: The language just consists of all words of length $\ne1$, thus you can write it even more simply as $\epsilon+(a+b)^2(a+b)^*$.

Comment: No, it’s not words that are not $\epsilon$. As I already wrote, it’s words of length $\ne1$. $\epsilon$ *is* in the language. Words of length $\ge2$ are in the language. Words of length $1$ are not in the language, as $1$ is the only nonnegative integer that cannot be written as a (possibly empty) sum of primes.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me again :o

Comment: Your regular expression is still wrong, since it includes $a$. Also you don't need to consider $0$ to be prime to have $\varepsilon$ in the language, since by definition of the Kleene star, $\varepsilon \in L$.

Comment: I’m sorry, but I have to do it again. $\epsilon$ is in the language because it is included in $X^*$ no matter what $X$ is. This has nothing to do with $0$ being prime. Even if $0$ were prime, this would not change the language, thus the second expression is wrong (it actually matches all strings).

Answer (score 1):

Every integer other than 1 is the sum of primes. So it’s either 0 or >= 2 symbols.

```
eps + (a+b)(a+b)(a+b)*
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to prove this is to show that the base language $L'=\{w∣|w|$
is prime $\}$ is regular. If it is, you can apply the known result that the $A^*$ of a regular language $A$ is regular.

Comment: It isn’t; that’s the point of the exercise.