# Finding two words of lengths that are relatively prime in a regular language?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, decision-problem

Given a regular language $L$ over a unary alphabet $\Sigma = \{ a \}$.

How to decide whether there are two words $w,w' \in L$ such that
the length of $w$ is relatively prime to the length of $w'$ ?

Comment: Why are you interested in such a contrived question?

Comment: This should help: [What are the possible sets of word lengths in a regular language?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-are-the-possible-sets-of-word-lengths-in-a-regular-language)

Answer (score 2):

Consider a minimal DFA for $L$. Each state in the DFA has one outgoing edge, so the DFA looks like a path entering a cycle. That means that $W = \{ n : a^n \in L \}$ is eventually periodic: for some $k,l$, for all $n \geq k$ it holds that $n \in W$ iff $n + l \in W$. We are now left with a problem in number theory, which I leave for you to ponder. (Try a few examples to see when an eventually periodic $W$ can fail to satisfy the property you're looking for.)

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Our regular language has additional property: for any words $w \in L$ we have also $w^n \in L$, for all $n \geq 1$. Actually we want to decide existence of $m$ such that all words longer than $m$ are in $L$. Due to your helpful comment we now see that it is equivalent to having a loop in DFA containing only accepting states.